# Can an iOS device in kiosk mode receive remote notification

Tags: ios, kiosk-mode, remote-notifications

Hello Stackoverflowers!

Before I embark on a small change to my app, I would like to know if an iOS device in kiosk mode can receive a remote notification (of the same app that's in the kiosk mode)?

Thanks!

Tomiris

Comment: A rather extensive Google search suggests that it was broken with an early iOS 11 beta, but is fixed now. I'd suggest trying to make sure though?

Comment: Do you have a reference URL? Thanks

Comment: I literally googled it ‍♂️

Comment: I can't seem to locate it. Please share the URL if you can. thanks

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=single+app+mode+remote+notifications

Comment: Ah, I had been searching using the term "kiosk" 
Still it's not very clear indeed